# Image loop only returns one image but should return them all

Tags: php

```
function all_images(&$post){
$content = $post->post_content;
if(preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+src="(.*?)"[^>]*>/', $content, $results)){
    $i = 0;
    $count = count($results);
    $count = $count - 1;
    while($i < $count)
    {
        foreach($results as $result){
            echo $result[$i];
        }
        $i++;
    }
  }
}
```

The above loop manages to get all of the images out of the original text. However, it only returns one image. I have tried several different combinations of while() and foreach() but it only ever returns one image. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: is $results supposed to be an array of arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$results[1] should be an array of all the matches on the first parenthesized subpattern, so something as simple as this should work:

```
if(preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+src="(.*?)"[^>]*>/i', $content, $results)){
    foreach($results[1] as $src)
    {
       echo "src is $src<br>";
    }        
}
```

Note I've used the /i modifier to make the match case insensitive, which might help you.

You might also want to supply some sample content you are trying to match against.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing $count = $count - 1?

You should be able to just do this:

```
if(preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+src="(.*?)"[^>]*>/', $content, $results)){
    foreach($results[1] as $result)
    {
        echo $result;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the structure of the array returned by [`preg_match_all`](http://docs.php.net/preg_match_all). So try this:

```
function all_images(&$post)
{
    $content = $post->post_content;
    if (preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+src="(.*?)"[^>]*>/', $content, $results)) {
        // $results[0] contains the whole match of the regular expression
        foreach ($results[0] as $result) {
            echo $result;
        }
    }
}
```